# Significant figures addition vs multiplication

Tags: notation

I was finding the molecular weight of $\ce{Br2}$ the other day and noticed that if I add the weight of $\ce{Br}$ to itself, $79.90+79.90=159.80$, that answer for the weight has $5$ significant figures. But if I just multiply the weight by $2$, $79.90 \times 2 = 159.8$, the weight has $4$ significant figures. If adding something to itself is the same as multiplying it by $2$ mathematically, which accuracy is more justifiable for my calculations in cases like this?

Comment: You forgot 2 * 0 = 0 . The multiplied answer contains 5 significant figs too

Comment: but you have to round it down to 4 because 79.90 only has 4 sig figs... http://www.sigfigscalculator.com/

Comment: According to your argument the added answer should also be rounded off to 4 significant values. It should not be 159.80

Comment: no, the rules for addition are that the lowest decimal place is kept, so two decimal places. Again, you can verify this with any online sig. fig. calculator

Comment: If this so, your argument "but you have to round it down to 4 because 79.90 only has 4 sig figs..." fails.

Comment: That is the rule for multiplication.

Comment: you can calculate using this calculator, i have recently used this calculator [https://www.sigfigcalculator.net/](https://www.sigfigcalculator.net/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculations are in accordance with the rules of the so-called *significance arithmetic* even though they yield different results.

When multiplying numerical values, according to the rules of significance arithmetic, the result is rounded to the *number* of significant digits in the factor with the least significant figures. When you multiply the value of the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br}}=79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}$ by 2, the value of the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br}}$ has four significant digits, whereas the factor 2 is assumed to be exact. Accordingly, the result is rounded to four significant digits:

$$M_{\ce{Br2}}=2M_{\ce{Br}}=2\times79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}=159.8\ \mathrm{g/mol}\tag1$$

When adding numerical values, according to the rules of significance arithmetic, the result is rounded to the *position* of the least significant digit in the most uncertain of the numbers being summed. When you add the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br}}=79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}$ to itself, the value of the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br}}$ is significant to the hundredth place. Accordingly, the result is rounded to the hundredth place:

$$M_{\ce{Br2}}=M_{\ce{Br}}+M_{\ce{Br}}=79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}+79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}=159.80\ \mathrm{g/mol}\tag2$$

However, **this concept of *significant digits* is just an oversimplified form of the concept of *uncertainty as a quantifiable attribute*.** In your question, you are testing the limits of the applicability of this simplification, which is certainly a good idea.

When a number is given without any further information, it is generally interpreted so that the last digit is rounded. Thus, the molar mass of $M_{\ce{Br}}=79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}$ is generally assumed to represent a value between $79.895\ \mathrm{g/mol}$ and $79.905\ \mathrm{g/mol}$, or $M_{\ce{Br}}=\left(79.900\pm0.005\right)\ \mathrm{g/mol}$.

Therefore, the assumed uncertainty of the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br}}$ is $u(M_{\ce{Br}})=0.005\ \mathrm{g/mol}$. (Note that, normally, the uncertainty corresponds to the estimated standard deviation; in this case, however, the uncertainty just indicates an interval corresponding to a high level of confidence.)

When you multiply the value of the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br}}$ by 2, you also have to multiply its uncertainty by 2 (the factor 2 is assumed to be exact):

$$M_{\ce{Br2}}=2M_{\ce{Br}}=2\times79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}=159.80\ \mathrm{g/mol}\tag{3a}$$

$$u(M_{\ce{Br2}})=u(2M_{\ce{Br}})=2u(M_{\ce{Br}})=2\times0.005\ \mathrm{g/mol}=0.010\ \mathrm{g/mol}\tag{3b}$$

When you add the value of the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br}}$ to itself, you also have to add the uncertainty to itself:

$$M_{\ce{Br2}}=M_{\ce{Br}}+M_{\ce{Br}}=79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}+79.90\ \mathrm{g/mol}=159.80\ \mathrm{g/mol}\tag{4a}$$

$$\begin{align}u(M_{\ce{Br2}})&=u(M_{\ce{Br}}+M_{\ce{Br}})=u(M_{\ce{Br}})+u(M_{\ce{Br}})=0.005\ \mathrm{g/mol}+0.005\ \mathrm{g/mol}\\&=0.010\ \mathrm{g/mol}\tag{4b}\end{align}$$

(Note that such a simple addition of uncertainties is not correct when the errors of the added values are uncorrelated, for example when calculating $M_{\ce{HBr}}=M_{\ce{H}}+M_{\ce{Br}}$.)

Both calculations yield the same results for the molar mass $M_{\ce{Br2}}$ ($\text{(3a)}$ and $\text{(4a)}$) as well for its uncertainty ($\text{(3b)}$ and $\text{(4b)}$). Thus, the molar mass of $M_{\ce{Br2}}$ is estimated to represent a value between $159.79\ \mathrm{g/mol}$ and $159.81\ \mathrm{g/mol}$, or $$M_{\ce{Br2}}=\left(159.80\pm0.01\right)\ \mathrm{g/mol}$$

By way of comparison, the result of the multiplication according to the rules of significance arithmetic $\text{(1)}$, $M_{\ce{Br2}}=159.8\ \mathrm{g/mol}$, represents a value between $159.75\ \mathrm{g/mol}$ and $159.85\ \mathrm{g/mol}$, or $$M_{\ce{Br2}}=\left(159.80\pm0.05\right)\ \mathrm{g/mol}$$ Thus, this approach overestimates the uncertainty of the result.

The result of the addition according to the rules of significance arithmetic $\text{(2)}$, $M_{\ce{Br2}}=159.80\ \mathrm{g/mol}$, represents a value between $159.795\ \mathrm{g/mol}$ and $159.805\ \mathrm{g/mol}$, or $$M_{\ce{Br2}}=\left(159.800\pm0.005\right)\ \mathrm{g/mol}$$ Thus, this approach underestimates the uncertainty of the result.

Answer (score 1):

If the $0$ in $79.90$ is important, the when you multiply by $2$ also, you get $159.80$ so there is no discrepancy. However, you do realise that suppose the weight was $79.904$ (in fact, it is !), writing 2 decimals only will be $79.90$ and times $2$ will produce $159.80$. However, if you had written $79.904$, you would have got $159.808$, which up to $2$ decimals is $159.81$

In multiplication, the simple rule is, the number of significant digits of the answer is that of the multiplicand with the least number of sinificant digits.

[Here](https://www.hccfl.edu/media/43516/sigfigs.pdf) is one such guide which you can go through.

Comment: When you multiply 2 (exact) times 79.90 (4 sig figs) it equals 159.80, but because you have to round to 4 sig figs, it's 159.8, right?

Comment: Try http://www.sigfigscalculator.com/ to see what I mean (enter "2.000000*79.90")